# Function template overload resolution with a pointer argument

Tags: c++, pointers, overload-resolution, function-templates, template-argument-deduction

The following code demonstrates the core of a C++ template metaprogramming pattern I have been using to determine whether a type `T` is an instantiation of a specific class template:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
struct S{};

template<class A, class B>
constexpr bool isS(const S<A,B>*) {return true;}

template<class T>
constexpr bool isS(const T*) {return false;}

int main() {
  S<int,char> s;
  std::cout<<isS(&s)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It features two overloads of a `constexpr` function template `isS`, and it outputs `1`, as expected. If I remove the pointer from the second `isS`, i.e. replace it with

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool isS(const T) {return false;}
```

the program unexpectedly outputs `0`. If both versions of `isS` make it through to the overload resolution phase of compilation, then the output implies that the compiler is choosing the second overload. I have tested this under GCC, Clang and vc++ using the online compilers [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual), and they all produce the same result. Why does this happen?

I have read Herb Sutter's ["Why Not Specialize Function Templates"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) article several times, and it seems that both `isS` functions should be considered to be base templates. If this is so, then it is a question of which one is the most specialised. Going by intuition and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4435618/1292784), I would expect the first `isS` to be the most specialised, because `T` can match every instantiation of `S<A,B>*`, and there are many possible instantiations of `T` that cannot match `S<A,B>*`. I'd like to locate the paragraph in the working draft that defines this behaviour, but I'm not entirely sure what phase of compilation is causing the problem. Is it something to do with *"14.8.2.4 Deducing template arguments during partial ordering"*?

This issue is particularly surprising given that the following code, in which the first `isS` takes a reference to `const S<A,B>` and the second takes a `const T`, outputs the expected value `1`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
struct S{};

template<class A, class B>
constexpr bool isS(const S<A,B>&) {return true;}

template<class T>
constexpr bool isS(const T) {return false;}

int main() {
  S<int,char> s;
  std::cout<<isS(s)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So the problem seems to be something to do with how pointers are treated.

Comment: A `const T` parameter is equivalent to a `T` parameter (so you'll get an exact match), and you need a qualification conversion from `S<int, char>*` to `S<int, char> const*`. Try using `S<int, char> const s;` instead in your `main`. -- The *more specialized* test happens very late in overload resolution, if other tests could not decide between the overloads. Here, we can select the second one earlier because it has a better rank (exact match vs qualification adjustment).

Comment: @dyp Ok, but then why does the compiler pick the first `isS` in the code snippet at the bottom, involving references? Doesn't the compiler need to do a qualification conversion from `S<int, char>&` to `const S<int, char>&` in this case?

Comment: @Ose No, `T*` to `const T*` is a qualification adjustment conversion, `T` to `const T&` is an identity conversion as the reference *binds directly* to the argument.

Comment: @TartanLlama Oh I see, thanks. TemplateRex updated their answer with this information, so I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the second overload will drop the top-level `const` inside the `const T`, it will resolve to `T*` during argument deduction. The first overload is a worse match because it will resolve to `S<int, char> const*`, which requires a const-qualification conversion.

You need to add `const` in front of your variable `s` in order for the more specialized overload to kick in:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
struct S {};

template<class A, class B>
constexpr bool isS(const S<A,B>*) {return true;}

//template<class T>
//constexpr bool isS(const T*) {return false;}

template<class T>
constexpr bool isS(const T) {return false;}

int main() {
  S<int,char> const s{}; // add const here
  std::cout<<isS(&s)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0084fca85778bc41)

Changing the first overload to a `const S<A,B>&`, will give the correct result because there is an identity conversion instead of a qualification adjustment.

> **13.3.3.1.4 Reference binding [over.ics.ref]**
>
> 1 When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the
>   implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion, unless the
>   argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the
>   parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a
>   derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).

**Note**: when in doubt about such argument deduction games, it's handy to use the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro which (on gcc/clang) will give you more information about the deduced types of the selected template. You can then comment out certain overloads to see how this affects the overload resolution. See this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/575c38233768f65c).

Comment: Thanks for this, but please see my comment above (below the question).

Answer (score 3):

Your second version doesn't give the answer you expect because the first version of `isS` requires an implicit conversion, whereas the second does not.

```
template<class A, class B>
constexpr bool isS(const S<A,B>*);

template<class T>
constexpr bool isS(const T);

S<int,char> s;
isS(&s);
```

Note that `&s` is of type `S<int,char>*`. The first `isS` is looking for a `const S<int,char>*`, so the pointer needs a conversion. The second `isS` is a direct match.

---

If you find yourself needing this pattern often, you could generalize it, like so:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct is_specialization_of<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then you check if a type is a specialization of `S` like this:

```
is_specialization_of<S, decltype(s)>::value
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but please see my comment above (below the question). Also, +1 for the generalisation - I hadn't thought of doing that!

Comment: I've noticed two shortcomings of your generalisation. One is that it says const TT<Ts...> is not a specialisation of TT<Ts...>. If this is desirable (as it is in my case), a second specialisation for const TT<Ts...> needs to be added. The other shortcoming is that it can't be used with class templates that have a mixture of type and non-type parameters (which is actually most of my use cases). I don't see a way of generalising it further to cover this case...

Comment: The first shortcoming can be solved by wrapping it in a template alias which calls `std::remove_const` on the type first, or even `std::decay` to remove everything. The second is a problem I've come across before and still do not have a good solution for.